# How to display particular message like alert message in asp.net3.5 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one form after clicking save button form redirecting to another page, but before redirecting another page it should display message like "Your data has been saved successfully".
What should i do?
Asp.net c#
Thsnk you.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have tried here? so, that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the confirm box here: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_popup.asp

Comment: This solution won't work for asp.net, if your are using asp.net buttons, you will have to use one of the solutions below

Answer (score 1):

say your button id was btnTest, use this code in the Page_Loadevent of your aspx Code behind Page:

```
btnTest.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return ShowSuccessMessage();");
```

and in your html page, use the following javascript function:

```
function ShowSuccessMessage()
{
alert("Your data has been saved successfully");
return true;
}
```

This way your button won't trigger a post back event till the alert message is shown

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:button id="btnSave" Text="Save"
       onclientclick="ShowMessage()"
       runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" />

<script type="javascript">

function ShowMessage()
{
  document.window.alert("Your data has been saved successfully.");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popmsg1", "<script language=javascript>alert('Your data has been saved successfully.'); location.href='page.aspx';</script>");
```

Comment: This will always cause the page to show the message and redirect, regardless of whether the button was clicked or not!

Comment: NO, put this code on button_click and it will only call when button  clicked.

Comment: your are right, it will work this way, but it is not the best way,

Comment: This is one of easiest approach.

Comment: :) The easiest approach is that of George, suppose the use wanted to show a confirm box, example ("Are your sure you want to save?"), will it work your way? ;)